# AWS EKS Nodes memory / CPU limits are low (10%)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have configured EKS on AWS with 4 nodes. When deploying my application, I've noticed that some pods cannot be setup because of insufficient resources (getting error 0/4 nodes are available: 4 Insufficient pods.)

When looking into k8s dashboard, I've noticed that only 10% of memory is used  (see picture)
[image: node memory]

I've used [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html) guide in order to set the things up.

How can I increase this limit and make my node used on full capacity?

Comment: share all available logs you have for your failures

Comment: @VKR, I dont have any failures....it's just about limited resources on nodes so k8s couldn't assign new pods

Comment: Did you check if all your nodes joined the cluster running kubectl get nodes?
Are you machine big enough? Which instances do you use?

Comment: @nicor88 nodes are joined. As you can see from picture above, there is 2Gb memory capacity but its limited to 200M for k8s use

Comment: I see, might it be that your application requires more than 200M?

Comment: @nicor88 application may require more than 200M. Question was about resource limits on node that is about 10% of node capacity.

Comment: I finally got it. I also followed the link that you used to setup the workers. In my case, I've no limits setup in the workers. It's quite interesting issue. Looking forward to heard the root cause of that.

Comment: can you do a `kubectl describe pod <podname> and see what particular resource is lacking in the pod deployment?

Answer (score 4):

You could find the full answer in this [source](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt).

The short one, the kubelet pods capacity is set by default because you have a maximum IP per network interface.